# R weird data frame subset formula vs. no formula

Tags: r, dataframe

Sorry for a kind of newb-ish question, as I've been using R for years, but I hadn't noticed this behavior until a student pointed it out to me and I can't explain it. First, build a little data frame. x-values greater than 100 are supposed to be illegal, but some have snuck in here.  We also have a "group" independent variable.:

```
x = c(20, 30, 50, 60, 150, 35, 55, 75, 45, 145)
g = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2)
df = data.frame(cbind(x,g))
```

Now, box plots, both grouped and ungrouped, which show all the data, including the illegal values, as they should:

```
boxplot(x~g)
boxplot(x)
```

So, we want to remove the illegal values by selecting only those rows in the frame with x-values less than 100.  The grouped version works exactly as expected:

```
boxplot(x~g, data=df[x < 100,])
```

But the ungrouped one doesn't!  All the data, including the values over 100, are plotted. Why does the previous one work and this one doesn't?

```
boxplot(x, data=df[x < 100,])
```

I'm sure I'm missing something simple, but for the life of me I can't figure out what it is, and I couldn't find the answer via Google or searching here.

Answer (score 2):

`boxplot` is an S3 generic, which means that depending on what the first argument is, totally different functions are actually being called. `boxplot.formula` has different arguments than `boxplot.default`. Specifically, `boxplot.default` has no data argument at all; it's probably being sucked into `...` and is then ignored as an unknown graphical parameter.

Try `boxplot(x[x < 100])` instead.

Comment: Of course! Yeah, I get it. Hard to explain to novices who are still just getting their head around the idea of functions in the first place, but at least now I know. (Incidentally, your approach is exactly the solution I gave to my students, but I wasn't sure why it worked that way.)

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because `boxplot` is reading `x` from the global environment, and not the data frame.

Note that this does not work as well:

```
df1 = df[x < 100, ]
boxplot(x, data=df1)
```

However, this works:

```
boxplot(df[df$x < 100, 'x'])
```

Comment: Not exactly; see my comment above.